# Spring bean @Component is not getting initialized and injected while application starts up but later it gets injected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-bean

I have class as below:

```
@Component
public class ServerFacade {
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private static RegisteredCacheService registeredCacheService;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
  registeredCacheService=
               applicationContext.getBean(RegisteredCacheService.class);
}

public static void doRegister()
{
  registeredCacheService.callRegistrationService();

}
}
```

And I have RegisteredCacheService class below

```
@Component
class RegisteredCacheService 
{
   public void callRegistrationService()
   {
     //some business logic
    }
}
```

Issue:
When my application comes up, I make a call to doRegister() of ServerDFacade class, and it does work, but in side this method, it tries to call to
`registeredCacheService.callRegistrationService();`, but strangely, I am seeing that `registeredCacheService` is NULL, now, once application comes up and then again if I make a call to `doRegister()`, this time `registeredCacheService` is NOT NULL and it works fine. I want to know the reason for this also the solution.

I tried one thing which also did not help. I changed the code like:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private RegisteredCacheService registeredCacheService;
```

And removed `@PostConstruct` and changed the static method to non-static method. In this case, `registeredCacheService` is always NULL even if application comes up fully.

Comment: I think the issue is with some Lazy instantiation, how I can make sure that RegisteredCacheService  bean gets initialized  and injected into ServerFacade. Just to give some idea, suppose during starting up of the application i make 10 calls to to doRegister() then first 4-5 does not work because bean is not injected, but rest of the call works because that time bean is not null.

Comment: You say "When my application comes up, I make a call to doRegister() of ServerFacade class": where do you exactly do this? Is this in another PostConstruct method? You have to be aware that, if your calls are not part of the Spring lifecycle, you can get into troubles..

Comment: I am calling this doRegister() from a method of SMartLifeCycle of Spring class, so when application comes up it makes a call to doRegister().

Comment: I would move the `registeredCacheService.callRegistrationService()` from `doRegister()` to `init()`, and remove the explicit call to `doRegister()` from the `SmartLifeCycle`. Or is there any special need on calling `doRegister()` explicitly?

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary that it gets called only during start-up, it can be called later as well. So I can not put in the init

Comment: Yes. The point is that the initialization logic that you have in the ´init()´ method is already going to be called **during the startup** of your application, because it is is annotated with [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations). You do not really need the ´SmartLifeCycle´.